# Confusion regarding differential in Do Carmo

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In Riemannian Geometry by Do Carmo, he defines the differential of a function between manifolds as the following:[image]

My confusion is the following; he defined the differential as a map between the tangent spaces however it is unclear how $\beta’(0)$ could possibly act on a smooth function as $\alpha’(0)$ defined previously did. Before, alpha was a sum of differential operators however here beta would be a column matrix and from what I can tell wouldnt even have any differential operators as entries. I understand that this proposition simply serves to introduce the differential but it doesn’t seem consistent with previous definitions

Comment: From Do Carmo's book, $\alpha^{'}(0)=x_i^{'}(0)(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})_0$. Similarly, $\beta^{'}(0)=y_i^{'}(0)(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i})_0$, and it mensions that its expression is with respect to the basis $\{(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i})_0\}$ of $T_{\varphi(p)} M_2$

Comment: @Tim it is not clear to me how $\beta’(0) = \gamma’_i (0) (\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i})_0 = (\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j})(x’_j (0))$

Comment: Take derivative of $\beta$ in (3), is derivative of $y^{-1}\circ \beta$,  
also you can review def 2.6, how to define $\alpha^{'}(0)f$, $f\circ \alpha = (f\circ x)\circ (x^{-1} \circ \alpha)$, treat it as a function from $R^{k_1}$ to $R^{k_2}$

Comment: OOh, also $T_pM^k$ is vector space isomorphic to $R^k$

Comment: @Tim yes, I know that $\alpha’(0)f = \frac{d(f\circ\alpha)}{dt} \big\vert_{t=0}$ and how he arrived to (3). My concern is how $(\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}) (x’_j (0)) f = \gamma’_i (0) (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i})_0$. The LHS is a row matrix multiplied by f whereas the RHS is a real number

Comment: @Tim how would I combine LHS with the basis of the tangent space? It is not clear to me how LHS is a linear differential operator acting on smooth functions

Comment: See my first comment, and review p.7,8: "symbol" $\alpha^{'}(0)$ represents both vector(p.8) in $R^n$ and functional(def2.6), $\beta^{'}(0)$ in (3) is only a vector in $R^m$.

Comment: @Tim Okay I think I know where my confusion was. So $\beta’(0)$ is a row vector as in (3) but in the same way that, if $\alpha(0) = (x_1(0),…,x_n(0)$, $\alpha’(0) = (x’_1(0),…,x’_n(0))$ is a vector. And in that case, $\beta’(0)$ acts on smooth functions in exactly the same way that $\alpha’(0)$ does, that is, if $\beta_i(0)$ represents the $i^{th}$ entry for the vector $\beta’(0)$, then $\beta’(0)f = \sum_i \beta_i(0) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}$?

Comment: Yes, but there is no f in the sum, $\beta’(0) = \sum_i \beta_i(0) (\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i})_0$, read the line above (3), "... $\beta’(0)$ with respect to the basis ...", it is a combination of the basis elements